# How to refer to an interval when it is not (yet) known whether it is open or closed? (Notation for intervals)

Tags: calculus, notation

**Is there a notation for referring to an interval when one does not know *a priori* whether it is open or closed (or some combination thereof)?**

---

> e.g. 1) if one were trying to determine the interval of convergence of a power-series representation of a function and had determined that the centre is $x = c$ and the radius is $r = R$, but do not yet know whether the end points $x = c \pm R$ are included or not, is there any way to refer to such an interval (other than the way I have done here)?

---

> e.g. 2) any situation in which the inclusion / exclusion of the endpoints is immaterial to the point at hand.

---

I tried searching for this here and on other sites, but the language is tricky, as anything about intervals or end-points “not being known” automatically brings up results related to the end-points not being determined (or their order not being known) etc.

I thought perhaps there’d be something like $[/(\, a, b\, )/]$ or $[/(\, a, b\,]/)$. Would be very interested if anyone knows of a common convention.

Comment: I'd denote such an interval as $I$. Perhaps I'd mention that $(a,b)\subseteq I\subseteq [a,b]$.

Comment: I don't know of any convention. Best I can come up with is $(a,b) \cup E$, where $E \subseteq \{a,b\}$ contains zero, one, or two endpoints. But that's pretty clunky. You could always define your own notation, e.g. "let $I(a,b)$ denote the interval $(a,b)$, possibly including $a$ and/or $b$".

Comment: I don't think there's a notation for this. If you have a particular context where you want to refer to such an interval, please [edit] the question to show us how you might want to do so. If you need the notation often in a document we might suggest something for you to define for your readers.

Comment: $\langle a, b\rangle$

Comment: @EthanBolker - the most common context for my needs would be when dealing with power-series, as in the first example. Either when discussing a) the interval before determining the endpoints or b) the series in a context where the endpoints are irrelevant (and so will not be determined).

Comment: @RaxAdaam Perhaps you can phrase your discussion in terms of the "interval of convergence $C$" without specifying $C$ in terms of its endpoints, so you don't have to decide whether either is in $C$.. Or try to rewrite using just the radius of convergence.

Comment: @EthanBolker based on the replies so far, that’s the sense I was getting, too (just referring to the centre and the radius). Was just curious to know if such a thing existed, but it doesn’t sound like it does. Certainly not worth inventing an idiosyncratic notation for such a small and specific purpose. Appreciate your time and comments, thank you kindly!